# Image animation doesn't work in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have made an animated profile picture and when hovered on it flips around and shows the backside. It works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari.

It does flip around, but the image changes back to the frontside but facing in opposite direction.

this is what I see 1 second after I hover on it. (This is the front-side, but flipped horizontally)

[image]

Link: http://www.ik-ben-zzp.nl/testsite/index.php

Here is the HTML CSS of the profile picture.

What is the problem here?

Thanks

```css
.roundedImage {
 overflow:hidden;
 width: 200px;
 height:200px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
    -webkit-animation:pop-in 0.8s;
    -moz-animation:pop-in 0.8s;
    -ms-animation:pop-in 0.8s;

}

.flip-container {
 perspective: 1000;
 z-index:3;
 margin-bottom:200px;
}
 
 .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
     -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 
}


.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  -ms-transition: 0.6s;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
}


.front, .back {
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}


.front {
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}


.back {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }
 
.front div, .back div {
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
 -webkit-animation:pop-in 0.8s;
    -moz-animation:pop-in 0.8s;
    -ms-animation:pop-in 0.8s;
 border: 4px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover')">

<div class="roundedImage">

<div class="flipper">

<div class="front">
<div style="background: url(Images/ProfileFront.jpg); height:200px; background-size: cover;"></div>
</div>

<div class="back">
<div style="background:url(Images/ProfileBack.jpg); height:200px; background-size:cover;"></div>
</div>

</div> <!--FLIPPER-->
</div> <!-- ROUNDED IMAGE -->
</div>  <!-- FLIP CONTAINER -->
```

Comment: what is your safari version? Safari version less than 7 does not support animation. Are you using windows safari? last version of safari on Windows   is 6.x

Comment: I use Windows Safari indeed.

Comment: Are you sure? cause the pop-in animation works just fine.

Comment: check your safari version and check this http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Comment: Version 5.1, but still the pop-in animation works. If it doesn't support animation then that one should be disabled too?

Comment: Please share pop-in animation css?

Comment: -webkit-animation:pop-in 0.8s;
    -moz-animation:pop-in 0.8s;
    -ms-animation:pop-in 0.8s;

Comment: hmm, maybe have limited support. It would be easy to pin point if you create a fiddle

Comment: Safari for Windows was last updated around 2012 and Apple have since stopped developing it. Most of today's CSS3 features lack full support in this browser so I'd expect to see anomalies like this.